# Is there a way to output a "/" in date validation

Tags: regex

Is there a way that within the pattern that the `/` is displayed when users enter a date.
So for example the date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`, when users enter in my form it enters as `ddmmyyyy` but I'd like the `/` to auto enter between each part to break the numbers up?

`\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}`

Comment: Did you try escaping the `/`? I mean, using `\/` instead? E.g., `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please explain what your question has to do with regular expressions? The expression you have shown seems to be just a regex search pattern and nothing which could be output. You should give some more context. Furthermore, please put code in a code block (don't write it as plain text). Lastly, you should explain what you mean by "auto enter" (although I have a vague idea what that could be).

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm not particularly "up" on the different languages on this, It's some code that is in my website that was done for me that I am trying to sort. My search on this type of code lead me to believe it was Regex, I'm unsure what the difference is in search patterens or what you suggest (very sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to insert `/` between the date-parts, then regexp-matching is not the right tool for you. You can try regexp-replace if thats availiable to you (pseudo-code):

`regex_replace("your-input-date-in-ddmmyyyy-format", (\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})(\d{2,4}), "$1/$2/$3")`

That way you build three groups `dd=$1`, `mm=$2` and `yyyy=$3` and insert `/` between each group.

But if you only want to match both formats `ddmmyyyy` AND `dd/mm/yyyy` you can use this modified regex of yours (escaped the `/` with `\` and made it optional with `?`):

`\d{1,2}\/?\d{1,2}\/?\d{2,4}`

**EDIT:**
Added PHP `preg_replace` example-link:
[phpliveregex](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/tIj#tab-preg-replace)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've pasted it in my code and doesn't seem to have the desired outcome. I want it to be so that when someone enters the DD then the "/" is entered automatically after them and the same after the MM too.
Thanks for your suggestions though, I did give them a go :)

Comment: @Wardy I've updated my answer with an `preg_replace` link. May be this helps :)